# Image binary is invalid when sending request to express application running on AWS, but it is valid on local

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I have an express backend application, which has an endpoint to receive an image as binary and compare it with another image using AWS Rekognition service. Here is the endpoint:

```
router.post("/profile_image", express.raw({ type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"], limit: "10mb" }), (req, res) => {
  const buff = req.body as Buffer;
  ...
  // Compare images with Rekognition
});
```

When I tested endpoint on my local machine using Postman, it works. But when I deploy it on AWS ECS it doesn't work anymore. The exact error is InvalidImageFormatException.

I started debugging by logging out some information and figured out that what the endpoint receives when I try on my local machine and on ECS are not the same buffer. The received buffer size for my local machine was 94875, which is the exact size of the image file. But the size of the received buffer on ECS was 170976. Just to ensure 100%, I tried to send back the received image directly from the endpoint. Now, the endpoint looked like this:

```
router.post("/profile_image", express.raw({ type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"], limit: "10mb" }), (req, res) => {
  const buff = req.body as Buffer;
  console.log(`buffer size: ${buff.byteLength}`);
  res.write(buff);
  res.send();
});
```

When I tested this on my local machine, the image is successfully rendered on Postman, but when I tested this on ECS, it sent back jibberish data, which seemed like it included some sort of metadata. Here is the head of the binary I received:

```
�PNG


IHDR��ռ pHYs��S�:tEXtTitlePDF CreatorA^�(tEXtAuthorPDF Tools AG�w0-zTXtDescription
...
```

I also built the docker image, and run it on my local machine, and tested it that way to see if something is wrong with the Dockerfile. But nothing has changed. It was again working on local machine.

I am using Node v20.8 and express v4.18.2. I have an AWS API Gateway in front of my ECS service (I don't spin up a gateway for local development). And the image I tested with has png mimetype. Both local and production tests are done using Postman.

**UPDATE:**
The reason seems to be due to API Gateway. I have created an ALB and connected the ECS just to be able to skip API Gateway. And this way, everything works perfectly fine. I am still not sure what does API Gateway do, and how to change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AWS API Gateway does not support binary requests out of the box,  and requires the following configuration:

1. Go to API -> Settings, and find Binary Media Types
2. Add the Content-Types in your endpoint to be interpreted as binary (image/jpeg, multipart/form-data etc.)
3. If you are using proxy for the endpoint, this should be sufficient, but if not, you should also add the Content-Type and Accept headers to the integration request of the endpoint as `method.request.header.Content-Type`